# Smarty template display space between charactes

Tags: php, smarty

How can i display in Smarty Template a string like this:
{Space}/{$variable}

Where space is blank string and {$variable} is send from PHP?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you mean {space} is space, you simply use:

```
 /{$variable}
```

(at the beginning there is a space before slash)

Comment: Thank you, but i use now &nbsp; from HTML

Comment: So what's the problem? I don't get it. Try to explain it in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
{assign var="Space" val="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"}
{Space}/{$variable}
```